# Can't connect to Azure Blob Storage from App Service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to connect to a Azure Blob Storage account from an App Service hosted within the same location and in the same resource group. However when attempting to create a container during startup I get the following exception:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An error
>   occurred while sending the request.) --->
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: An error occurred
>   while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
>   An error occurred while sending the request. --->
>   System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A connection with the server could
>   not be established

The inner exception is:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A connection with the server could not be established
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
>      at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.d__105.MoveNext()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I have double checked the account name, URL and access keys. I have also tried cycling the access keys to be sure. I have tried connecting to another storage account from the same app service and that also fails.

There are no app firewalls or VNets in place on either resource and I am at a loss as to what could be causing the issue.

Comment: Check the InnerExceptions propery of the `AggregateException`, it will contain more detailed information.

Comment: True that, if you see a `400 Bad Request` that's very likely a bad key incident. Maybe you're reading/forming a corrupt/empty string as key? You'll need to show some code.

Comment: I have added the inner exception to the original question. It seems to be a 500 Internal Server error instead of a 400 Bad Request. As far as I can tell there seems to be something blocking outgoing HTTP connections from the app service. However there isn't any Azure functionality in place that would stop those connections.